# docker rootless daemon fails on RHEL VMs with centrifydc enabled with error

Tags: linux, docker, centrify, rootless

docker rootless daemon fails on RHEL VMs with centrifydc enabled with error

error:

```
dockerd-rootless.sh: failed to load listeners: can't create unix socket /run/user/uid/docker.sock: chown /run/user/uid/docker. sock: invalid argument
```

But works fine when centrifydc is disabled. No helpful logs from centrify, any help please

Comment: I think this issue could be related to the following problem:

Having 64K sub-IDs should be ok for most cases, but to allow
nesting user namespaces, an enormous number of sub-IDs would
be needed
• Potential sub-ID (up to 4G entries) starvation, especially in
LDAP environments with many users